# Android layout replacing a view with another view on run time

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

I have a `xml`-layout file main with two textviews A/B and a view C.
I have two other `xml`-layout files `option1` and `option2`.
Is it possible to load either `option1` or `option2` in run time via Java into C? If so, what function do I have to use?

Answer (score 386, accepted):

You could replace any view at any time.

```
int optionId = someExpression ? R.layout.option1 : R.layout.option2;

View C = findViewById(R.id.C);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) C.getParent();
int index = parent.indexOfChild(C);
parent.removeView(C);
C = getLayoutInflater().inflate(optionId, parent, false);
parent.addView(C, index);
```

If you don't want to replace already existing **View**, but choose between option1/option2 at initialization time, then you could do this easier: set `android:id` for parent layout and then:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent);
View C = getLayoutInflater().inflate(optionId, parent, false);
parent.addView(C, index);
```

You will have to set "index" to proper value depending on views structure. You could also use a **ViewStub**: add your C view as ViewStub and then:

```
ViewStub C = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.C);
C.setLayoutResource(optionId);
C.inflate();
```

That way you won't have to worry about above "index" value if you will want to restructure your XML layout.

Comment: Must I remove the fragment, or will the fragment also be removed?

Comment: @KarlMorrison This question is almost 4 years old and has nothing to do with fragments. I suggest to file a new question and/or take a look at `android.app.FragmentTransaction` and it's `replace()` method.

Comment: It is a pity your answer is too complex - in the comments - for novice Android programmers :-(

Comment: @AntonioSesto what is too complex? Where did you get confused?

Comment: @broot I want to add Images daynamically to my linearlayout that i have done. later I remove some of images from layout. then I want to restore it at its own position from where I have removed. means I want to add images without removing child's parent can you please hlep me ?

Comment: After I changed orientation, it went back to the old view. Any way to workaround this bug, aside from implementing viewflipper/switcher?

Comment: @pete it's not a bug. After rotation the activity is destroyed and recreated - so your xml is once again used to recreate the layout - so once again you have to manipulate the layout to your liking. I suggest you write a method that manipulates the Views and call that method after every onCreate()

Answer (score 44):

And if you do that very often, you could use a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) or a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) to ease view substitution.

Comment: Yes, if there is question of alternate views, then view flipper/switcher is better to use

Comment: @Shail Adi, did you try to goole an ViewSwitcher tutorial code ?

Comment: I know this is old - but the caveat is that a ViewSwitcher initializes and holds both Views in itself (a FrameLayout).

Comment: This should be the recommend answer. Why not just use a ready made well tested solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
private void replaceView(View oldV,View newV){
        ViewGroup par = (ViewGroup)oldV.getParent();
        if(par == null){return;}
        int i1 = par.indexOfChild(oldV);
        par.removeViewAt(i1);
        par.addView(newV,i1);
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score 0):

it work in my case, oldSensor and newSnsor - oldView and newView:

```
private void replaceSensors(View oldSensor, View newSensor) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) oldSensor.getParent();

            if (parent == null) {
                return;
            }

            int indexOldSensor = parent.indexOfChild(oldSensor);
            int indexNewSensor = parent.indexOfChild(newSensor);
            parent.removeView(oldSensor);
            parent.addView(oldSensor, indexNewSensor);
            parent.removeView(newSensor);
            parent.addView(newSensor, indexOldSensor);
        }
```