# Replace a view with other view By code

Tags: android

I want to replace a view with other other by code
For example i need to change a `imageview` to `progressBar` by code.

```
public void changeToProgressBar(ImageView imageview,Context context){
            ProgressBar one = new ProgressBar(context);
            one.setLayoutParams(imageview.getLayoutParams());
            imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //NOW I NEED TO PLACE 'one' EXACTLY THE PLACE WHERE  'imageview' WAS THERE 
        }
```

I need to use this many place. I know to set by sending the parent `viewgroup`.
Is there anyway to get the parent `viewgroup` from `imageview`
Thanks

Comment: the same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3760027) :)

Answer (score 10):

This is trivial to do and other posters have linked to or hinted at the solution. You can get the parent of a View by View.getParent(). You need to cast the returned value to a ViewGroup (q: can a View's parent be anything else than a ViewGroup?). Once you have the parent as a ViewGroup you can do ViewGroup.removeChild(viewToRemove) to remove the old view and add the new one using ViewGroup.addChild(viewToAdd).

You might also want to add the new view at the same index as the remove view to make sure that you don't put the new view on top of or below other views. Here's a complete utility class for you to use:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ViewGroupUtils {

    public static ViewGroup getParent(View view) {
        return (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
    }

    public static void removeView(View view) {
        ViewGroup parent = getParent(view);
        if(parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }

    public static void replaceView(View currentView, View newView) {
        ViewGroup parent = getParent(currentView);
        if(parent == null) {
            return;
        }
        final int index = parent.indexOfChild(currentView);
        removeView(currentView);
        removeView(newView);
        parent.addView(newView, index);
    }
}
```

Something to consider is that you'll lose any positioning in a relative layout when you replace one view with another. One solution to this would be to make sure that the view you want to replace is wrapped in a another view and that wrapped container view is the one that is positioned in a relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

For this, take both `imageview` and `progressBar` and set the visibility according to your requirements.

### For example

If you want `progressBar` to be visible, put `setvisibility(Visibility.GONE)` for `imageview` and put  `setvisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)` for `progressBar`

Comment: Thank for your answer. I know that, but for this i need to declare the progressbar in my xml. Here i'm creating it by code

Comment: yourview.removeView(imageview) and youtview.addView(progressbar)

Comment: How to get the `yourview` form my `imageview`

Answer (score 0):

Just as User333 described that could be one solution..
It's also possible to delete the imageview by calling `yourview.removeView(imageview)` and then create your progress bar and put that inside the view instead by `yourview.addView(progressbar)`

Comment: How to get the `yourview` form my `imageview`

Comment: 'yourview', is the view containing your 'imageview'.. ex. a 'LinearLayout' or some other view ?

Comment: you can also do it like this, imageview.getParent() which returns the view that is containing your imgageview..

Comment: No. getParent will only return the view not the parent viewgroup. We cannot add view to another view group

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the view you would like to change by calling findViewById() from the activity level
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)
 Then find the sub view you would like to  change
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int) 
Then use the functions from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html to manipulate the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Android Activities view from any other simple java class or in other activity.
you only need to pass current view and get your element by this view you want to change 
**As :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting UI
    View currentView = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

    //showHeaderLayout is simple java class or it can be any activity
    changeLayout.setView(currentView);

}
```

**Class : changeLayout**

```
 public class changeLayout{
    public static View setView(final Activity activity, final View myView)
     {
      // myView helps to get Activity view , which we want to change.
      TextView tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tv); 
      tv.setText("changs Text Via other java class !!");
     }
  }
```

**Note : Passing view makes you able to change any activity view outside an Activity.**

Answer (score 0):

I think following ould be the best approach as in this we don't need to set layout params.

```
setvisibility(Visibility.GONE)
setvisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that following link not only help you, but even shows you the direction for your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760027/3133932