# Android: Video restarts after orientation changes

Tags: android

I am playing video in android using VideoView by using different activity other than main activity.

At the time of video is running when i changes the orientation of phone it stops that video then project run from main activity and later video starts from beginning. Even to play video from beginning it taking too much time .

Can i play video immediately and from that position where it stops when orientation changes.

Please suggest me solution.

Thanks in advance.

Nilesh.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the current position of the video using `VideoView.getCurrentPostion()` in onSavedInstance() method. And can start the video using `VideoView.seek(pos)` and then `VideoView.start()`

Note: run the seek() and start() methods in a thread.

Comment: videoView.seek and videoView.start or mediaplayer.start or mediaplayer.seek

Answer (score 5):

Override the following Method in your activity

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    System.out.println("IN onConfigurationChanged()");
}
```

and add the following property in your manifest file in your activity tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: Thanks Usman, your solution work for me. all who read this please please give a "up vote" for any one solution which work for you so other can get help.

Answer (score 3):

To help any stumbler

if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

if your android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">

Reference: See Mohit comment on this question [Android application restarts on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075540/android-application-restarts-on-orientation-change)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

-thanks to user 'Ashok'
source : [Rotating phone restarts video on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983583/rotating-phone-restarts-video-on-android)