# How to keep playing video while changing to landscape mode android

Tags: java, android, orientation, android-videoview

I'm playing video (on `VideoView`) on portrait mode (not on full screen) and when I change to

landscape mode the video stop.

When I change it to landscape that video will appear on full screen and will keep playing.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38971707/1153703

Answer (score 58, accepted):

all you need to do is add this to activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Your Video activity should look something like this.

```
 <activity android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity" 
  android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012863):

> If your target API level 13 or higher, you must include the `screenSize` value in addition to the `orientation` value as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange). Your Video activity should look something like this.
>
> ```
>  <activity android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity" 
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
> ```

And then add the following method to VideoPlayerActivity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but when i playing in portrait mode the video is small compared to landscape mode that video should be full screen but video still stay small with this code

Comment: Superb I was searching for it from a long time :P At-last

Comment: This is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

**Full Screen Landscape Video**

AndroidManifext.xml (Setting the orientation)

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Video1"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Video1.xml Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Video1">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
</VideoView>
```

Video1.java Code :

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Video1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private VideoView videoView;
private MediaController mediaController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video1);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String fullScreen =  getIntent().getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");
    if("y".equals(fullScreen)){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.YOUR_VIDEO_NAME);

    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

    mediaController = new FullScreenMediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
    }
}
```

FullScreenMediaControler.java Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class FullScreenMediaController extends MediaController {

private ImageButton fullScreen;
private String isFullScreen;

public FullScreenMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {

    super.setAnchorView(view);

    //image button for full screen to be added to media controller
    fullScreen = new ImageButton (super.getContext());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    params.rightMargin = 80;
    addView(fullScreen, params);

    //fullscreen indicator from intent
    isFullScreen =  ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().
            getStringExtra("fullScreenInd");

    if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_exit);
    }else{
        fullScreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_fullscreen);
    }

    //add listener to image button to handle full screen and exit full screen events
    fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Video1.class);

            if("y".equals(isFullScreen)){
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "");
            }else{
                intent.putExtra("fullScreenInd", "y");
            }
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: for full screen landscape video

Comment: Giving `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` will fix activity in **landscape** mode only(user can't change it to portrait).I believe you should read question again.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you specify otherwise, a configuration change (such as a change in screen orientation, language, input devices, etc) will cause your current activity to be destroyed, going through the normal activity lifecycle process of onPause(), onStop(), and onDestroy() as appropriate. If the activity had been in the foreground or visible to the user, once onDestroy() is called in that instance then a new instance of the activity will be created, with whatever savedInstanceState the previous instance had generated from onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

So what happened behind the scenes: currnet VideoView Activity (landscape) is destroyed, a new VideoView Activity (portrait) is created due screenOrientation configuration has been changed, and destoryed immidiately (where you can see the effects on screen), last activity in stack is shown.

Try to handle this methods and check

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    mVideoView.resume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mVideoView.suspend();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```