# VideoView plays in portrait mode but not in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have created two layout one normal layout and one for landscape. below is the `VideoView` xml for both the orientation. The video is streamed from an URL. The video is played perfectly in portrait mode but when is change the orientation to landscape mode the video is not played it just keeps on showing me the `ProgressDialog`. The below code may help in understanding my problem.

**Normal Layout:**

```
<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vv_item_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

**Landscape Layout:**

```
<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vv_item_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java code for executing the `VideoView`:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
vvItemVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getResUrl()));
vvItemVideo.requestFocus();
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Retrieving data ...", true, true);
vvItemVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.e(TAG, "video is prepared");
        progDailog.dismiss();
        vvItemVideo.seekTo(position);
        vvItemVideo.start();
        final MyMediaController mc = new MyMediaController(ItemDetailActivity.this);
        vvItemVideo.setMediaController(mc);
        mc.setAnchorView(vvItemVideo);
        mc.show();
    }
});
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: refer this thread might help to you :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031295/how-to-keep-playing-video-while-changing-to-landscape-mode-android

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't need to handle the orientation change manually, define your activity like below in manifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name="youractivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

This will manage the orientation change and you don't need to code for it.

And use this code in `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    linear_layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
} else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    linear_layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 250);
}
videoView.setLayoutParams(linear_layoutParams);
```

Comment: yes but what happens in this situation is that the video wont become full screen the width and height are same when they were portrait

Comment: Yes because you need height of video to be "250" in portrait mode. What you can do is, you can change the height of `videoView` in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

Comment: i got the answer from the comment from kushan2 but i would like to know how you would do that

Comment: So are you trying my suggestion ?

Comment: yes i will but explain how to do that in `onConfigurationChanged()`

Comment: @vishwajitPalankar , i have edited my answer. Please see and try. And let me know if it works for you.