# playing video while changing to landscape mode android

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-orientation, landscape-portrait

I am using Listview
I'm playing video (on VideoView) on portrait mode (not on full screen) and when I change to
landscape mode the video stop.
When I change it to landscape that video will appear on full screen and will keep playing.
Any Suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep playing video while changing to landscape mode android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031295/how-to-keep-playing-video-while-changing-to-landscape-mode-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your manifest for that activity, and ensure the activity does not redraw the views.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Please note that if you have handled the orientation changes for this activity separately, then adding this would skip that.

Comment: I am using Listview and After  rotating landscape ,i want to that all view hide but video show in landscape mode.