# picking only portrait layout on screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-manifest

I am beginner in Android Development. I have two layouts (portrait and Landscape) for a single activity. In my layout, I have a VideoView and a custom Media player.
whenever I rotate the phone screen the video begins from start for this issue and  saving the data on screen rotation I have added this in my manifest file

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

After adding this in my manifest, my video is playing normally but my activity is picking only Portrait layout whenever I rotate the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep playing video while changing to landscape mode android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031295/how-to-keep-playing-video-while-changing-to-landscape-mode-android)

Comment: whenever you apply `screensize` then you have to manage on your own in method `onConfigurationChanged`. In This case `onCreate()` calls only once. You have to reshape your activity as per your requirement. If you not apply `screensize` then your activity created again

Comment: @GowthamanM my issue is not about saving the video state on screen rotation but picking the same mode (portrait) of layout evertimes.

Answer (score 0):

use below code when orientation change

```
        switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
                case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                    setContentView(R.layout.control_layout_vertical);
                    break;
                case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                    setContentView(R.layout.control_layout_horizontal);
                    break;
            }
```