# NullPointerException when using .addView to ViewGroup

Tags: view, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout, viewgroup

I'm trying to use `.addView` to add another `LinearLayout` to the `ViewGroup`.

I am getting the following error on LogCat:

> 05-21 16:23:04.096: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-21 16:23:04.096: E/AndroidRuntime(2086): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-21 16:23:04.096: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3148)
>   05-21 16:23:04.096: E/AndroidRuntime(2086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3131)

This is the code being called:

```
final LinearLayout eventContainerSub =
                        (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.event_container);

                final LinearLayout eventContainer =
                        (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.eventContainer);

                eventContainer.addView(eventContainerSub);
```

Here is the `ViewGroup` (the first linear layout):

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/eventContainer"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:duplicateParentState="true">
```

And this is the (second) `LinearLayout` I'm adding to the (first one) `LinearLayout` above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/eventContainerSub">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both containers have the exact same name..eventContainerSub.

There is no eventContainer, change the view group to be the container as you planned..

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/event_container"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:duplicateParentState="true">
```

and make sure the code is asking for the right Ids:

final LinearLayout eventContainerSub =
                        (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.eventContainerSub);

```
            final LinearLayout eventContainer =
                    (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.event_container);
```

I'd also suggest you first remove the SubContainer from the view if it got inflated, as that view already has a parent and you cannot attach the SubContainer to two parents.

Either leave the subcontainer from this file and create a new one, or remove from the parent and only then add to the ViewGroup you want.

[Android layout replacing a view with another view on run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334048/android-layout-replacing-a-view-with-another-view-on-run-time)

[Call removeView() on the child's parent first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526874/call-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first)

Comment: Did you try now adding the second contain via XML but via code?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, could you word that a little different?

Comment: null pointer error? are you sure its the same error and not a new one? can you put the stack trace?

Comment: so glad to help, sometimes you look at your own code for hours not understanding why it's not working..I feel your pain buddy and glad to help ;)