# Replace the layout of the fragment in onActivityResult() after success reponse from startActivtyForResult()

Tags: android, android-fragments

Initially when the `fragment` is loaded it has layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.authenticate, null);
    return view;
}
```

Later in the `fragment` I'm perfomring a functionality which will call `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

If the reponse is successful, I want to replace the layout of the fragment with another layout, say: `R.layout.success`

In `onActivityResult()` what should I write.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Some code
    if(success){
        // WHAT TO CODE HERE TO REPLACE THE LAYOUT R.layout.authenticate TO R.layout.success
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334048/android-layout-replacing-a-view-with-another-view-on-run-time

Comment: @Andy should add this answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an index while calling the `Fragment` from the `Activity` in a `Bundle` as

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("index", 0);//pass 0 for the first time and pass 1 from onActivityResult
MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in `Fragment` get the index and load the layout accordingly

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     int index=getArguments().getInt("index");
     View view = null;
     if(index == 0) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.authenticate, null);
     } else {
        //another layout to load
     }
     return view;
}
```

Comment: `onCreateView()` is not getting called when the child activity is finihed. Flow is starting from `onResume()`