# how to include one layout to another layout based on spinner selection?

Tags: android, xml

My spinner has 3 strings. Those are `{India, china, usa}`

If user select India then `India.xml` should be included in `activity_main.xml`

If user select china then `china.xml` should be included in `activity_main.xml`

If user select usa then `usa.xml` should be included in `activity_main.xml`

Is it possible? If yes, how to do it? If not, how can I acheive my requirement?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know about fragment?

Comment: yes sir, actually I am implementing this in fragment only.@KuLdipPaTel

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334048/android-layout-replacing-a-view-with-another-view-on-run-time

Comment: Sir, I did not understand what they told in that link. Please don't close off this question as duplicate. I need solution.@Kuffs

Comment: Use fragments mate :)

Comment: I don't know about this sir. can you tell me?@M.SaadLakhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this guide buddy
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

By following this guide you will be able to do your job just use spinner instead of buttons in this example then you are good to go

Comment: Sir I am implementing this Fragment, in this case, will your guide helpful to me?

Comment: Best of luck do accept the answer if it helps and upvote .. only if it helps otherwise ignore it because your answer and upvote helps others too to achieve this . Happy coding bro :)

Comment: I was implementing my code by taking that as a  reference. Here I am facing problem. In fragment_one.xml I was implemented 4 cardviews and in fragment_two.xml i was implemented 1 cardview. When I am selecting 1st item in spinner, I need to display fragment_one.xml and When I am selecting 2nd Item in spinner I need to display fragment_two.xml. Now, here what happened is when I was selected 1st item It displays 4 cardviews in fragment_one.xml but when selected 2nd item It replaced the 1st card in fragment_one.xml and displayed remaining 3rd cards in fragment_one.xml. Why?help me. @M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: Please anyone can help me. I am almost done but at last I am facing this issue.

Comment: there should be an error bro ... Normally when new fragment loads it replaces the old one ... can you please share your code so I may look it?